# How to prevent AD object information export by a LDAP Export tool from workgroup computer

Tags: account-security, active-directory, network-access-control

I have a question regarding Active Directory Security. I can export Active Directory Object information by any 3rd party LDAP Export tool from any workgroup computer which is connected in my network. For example: I used LDAPDomainDump tool. I installed it in a linux machine which is connected in my network but not in my domain. When I ran it, it showed to put a user credential which can be either administrator or even normal user. If I give the normal domain user credential and after that I can easily export my Active Directory object information. Now, it is a big concern for my security. If I need admin credential to export it then it is okay for me but how can I export it by a normal user's credential from a workgroup device.

I checked my audit log and found that it's accepted as a Logon Type 3 request. Now, my question is how can I prevent it? Is there any way to prevent it by any AD policy or 3rd party tool or from network side?

Comment: A workgroup computer that isn't connected to the domain? How does that work? And was any information sensitive? Anything that a user of the domain shouldn't have access to? Typically, the info from tools like that ***needs*** to be available to users to function on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

By design, Active Directory makes *a lot* of information readable to low-privileged users, and a Windows domain relies on that being the case. You could potentially go through changing permissions of various objects/schemas using the AD management tools and ADSI, but you are *very* likely to end up breaking your domain in all kinds of weird ways unless you really know what you're doing.

If the fact that a low privileged user can query LDAP to obtain things like lists of users or computers is a concern for you, then you need to seriously reconsider whether Active Directory is an appropriate system for you to be using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want one thing that, a normal user cannot export my all active directory information from a workgroup computer. How can I do it

Comment: @Md.RubiatHaque They can't export *all* your information unless something has gone very badly wrong with your AD setup - things like password hashes are only accessible to highly privileged users.